# Converting string with color name to color"id"

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, gdi+

I have

```
public String colorid = "Blue";
```

And

```
  Sbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Convert.ToInt32(colorid));
```

I want to be able to define the colorid somewhere else, that's why I wrote the SolidBrush code like that. Now this doesn't work and I would appreciate it if someone could help me

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing?  How does it not work?  What else have you tried?

Comment: I'm guessing from `SolidBrush` that this is WPF - you should tag it as such for clarity.

Comment: @DanPuzey, `SolidBrush` is GDI+. In WPF it's `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: So it is - apologies!  Still, the GDI tag is useful :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use creating color from name

```
Color.FromName("Blue")
```

Comment: Awesome! One more thing, how can I make 
    public String colorid = "Blue"; (in class Snake)
Accessible in Form1 like this:
      Snake.colorid = "Black";

Comment: I did what you said, and now have     public static readonly String colorid = "Black";
But this isn't working :/

Comment: I want to assign other values to colorid (other colours) in Form1

Comment: Why not create this as a new question.

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven sorry, I thought you want it read-only. If you want to change color value, you can use `public static string ColorId`

Answer (score 2):

This way support both color name and html colors:

```
string nm = "Blue"; // or f.ex. "#0000ff"

if (nm.StartsWith("#")) {
    return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(nm);
}
else {
    return Color.FromName(nm);
}
```

Comment: +1 OP didn't ask for html colors, but I didn't know about `ColorTranslator`

Comment: Thanks, this is gonna be helpful!